# Why the arrow keys don't work on vertical menuStrip?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a form with a menuStrip control (the layout VerticalStackWithOverflow). How could I enable the arrow keys to navigate this menu? Also how could I get the event of pressing Enter on the selected item?

Comment: It is WinForms.

Comment: The arrow keys and enter key should work out of the box. press `Alt` when the form is open and then you can navigate with the arrows ... hit enter to invoke the menu item click event.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But is there any way I could navigate that menu without pressing Alt (a hidden setting to disable that)? Or should I send Alt programmatically? I'm trying to build a program launcher and the arrow keys should work instantly.

Comment: not that i know of ... you probably going to have to set focus by code.

Answer (score -1):

I dont particularly know about that control, but the arrows and Enter dont work with TextBox either. The default key form moving between controls is Tab. You have to override the keypress event and add that feature by invoking SelectNextControl method something like this(in this case Enter)

```
private void keypressed(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        this.SelectNextControl((Control) sender, true, true, true, true);
     }
 }
```